# How could I get identifierForVendor for any app (not developed by me)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uniqueidentifier, bundle-identifier

My goal is to obtain the [`identifierForVendor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor) for a specific app that is on the App Store and that I have **NOT** developed nor have access to. Lets say this app's bundle id is `com.example.app`

And just to preface, I was able to grab the identifierForVendor of `com.example.app` by sniffing the network requests. However, this is not an efficient or scalable way to get it for multiple devices. So, I am looking into other methods.

I have tried to get the identifierForVendor of `com.example.app` by creating a custom iOS app on Xcode with the bundle id `com.example.test`

I was hoping the identifierForVendor would be the same considering their documentation notes that apps with the same bundle id will have the same identifierForVendor, but it was not. It seems that the identifierForVendor is also based on the developer profile or something.

Is there anyway for me to get this identifierForVendor value of an external app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that you cannot.

Apple does not provide any details on how this identifier is computed.

The identifier is unique for apps with the same initial bundle id components for a given developer on each device.

For example, apps with bundle ids `com.example.app1` and `com.example.app2`, both from *developer1* would have the same `identifierForVendor` on a given device.

An app with the bundle id `com.example.app3` on the same device but from a different developer would have a different `identifierForVendor`; that is the *for vendor* bit.

Even if you use the same bundle ID prefix you won't get the same identifier as an app from another developer.

You should also note:

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them.

Comment: Ok thank you for you answer, makes sense! I figured the developer was somehow factored into it. I will look into other ways to get around this limitation. Thank you.